# Running windows command from linux

Tags: linux, windows, command

EDIT:

To be precise i wanted to control a windows host from a Linux command line.
Like executing a command under windows through ssh session or telnet from linux.

Windows doesn't have any inbuilt sshd server like linux. 
So i would like to know whether it is possible or not.

Comment: Do you wan to run the same executable as you would on Windows, or are you just looking for the same command, but on Linux?

Comment: You could install Cygwin's SSH daemon on Windows, but there must be a simpler way.

Comment: I want to execute a standard windows command from Linux 
eg. arrib 
@hal is'nt their is any way by which i need not to install any software on windows.

Comment: Working with command lines and operating systems is **not a programming problem**! It belongs on **superuser.com**!

Comment: Windows terminal services allows remote desktops etc.

Comment: You could install Powershell Server on your windows box, then you can ssh from your Linux box to a powershell terminal on your windows box.  See http://www.powershellserver.com/

Comment: But that require to modify each window guest, isn't their is any way to achieve this without modifying.

Comment: I understand this question is really old, but does anybody know how to solve this problem. I would like to run a windows tool installed in a VM on a linux host.

Answer (score 4):

You do it with `winexe`  the  look at [winexe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winexe/).

The page says it is capable of of running command on  Windows NT/2000/XP/2003 systems from GNU/Linux (and possibly also from other Unices capable of building the Samba 4 software package).

I can also tell you that after configuring the windows firewall properly it also works on Windows 7 and Windows server 2008.